# Sound plays even though on awake is unticked unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, sprite, collision

I looking into similar threads with this issue and sadly my issue is not being resolved how theirs was. I have a sprite that when it is collected a sound is played. As soon as the game starts any audio I attach is playing. I have deleted the sprite and remade it and the issue is still the same, however for my 7 other sprites there is no issue.

Does anyone know why this may be an issue?

If needed i can supply code however i don't think it is a code based issue

Comment: Is there anything in the object's Start() or Awake() functions that might play sound? Can you confirm once again that "Play On Awake" us unticked, and also still unticked while you run it and inspect the object in the tree?

Comment: There are no objects with Play on Awake, my on start is the same for all sprites. It is 
 `void Start()
    {
        audioSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }`

No other sprite is playing a sound only one specific one even with all code and settings the same

Comment: what should cause it to play its sound, are you sure thats not somehow triggered

Comment: it is supposed to be played when a collision occurs, no collision is occurring though. I have it set up the same as the other sprites, i have even deleted the sprite and set it up again and the same issue occurs. Just found it very strange for one sprite to cause this and not any others

Comment: are you sure its not a collison thing? such as touching ground etc

Comment: I have the box collider set to be just a small bit bigger than the item itself and it is a trigger, it should only play on this collision.
The on awake setting in the audio source is not selected. This is why i find it so bizarre

Comment: Also it is a 2D game and the sprite objects im colliding with do not move, only the main character does

Comment: then logic says it has to be thinking it hits something

Comment: I will keep looking into it, thank you for your help!

Comment: I am having this problem. I have literally done everything, I deleted the audio from the hierarchy, I unticked Play on Awake, I deleted the code to play the audio in all scripts, I disable the audio source, I disabled the reverb filter, I ticked "Load in background", I unticked preload audio, I restarted unity, I restarted my pc, I uninstalled unity and reinstalled it, I reimported the audio, I asked on unity's discord (nobody helped), I asked on unity answers (nobody helped) and I even changed my audio from wav to mp3. Nothing fixes this bug. Unity is broke and the developers of it dont care.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, old post but I didn't see my solution anywhere else.  I found that the default script in the audio source game object was playing the clip in the start method.  By commenting this out, I was able to stop it from playing when the game was started.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your audio source has a box named "Play On Awake" ticked.

I was looking for the same answer, as my audio sources also played when starting the game. After reading this question, somehow I realized there was a box ticked which I didn't bother looking over.

If your box is not ticked, then try writing in the Start method:

```
this.yourAudioSource.playOnAwake = false;
```